# Are bitcoin transaction confirmation times limited by block size?

Tags: transactions

The following commentator [writes](https://www.monero.how/why-monero-vs-bitcoin):

> When transactions are announced to the Bitcoin networks, they appear as part of a ‘block’. Bitcoin blocks are produced on average every 10 minutes. Bitcoin blocks have a maximum size, so if there is no room then your transaction will be delayed. If you are desperate to have your transaction included in a Bitcoin block promptly, you will have to increase the transaction fees that you pay to the Bitcoin network.

Now it seems if you had a flexible block size - this transaction confirmation time issue would be addressed.

My question is: **Are bitcoin transaction confirmation times limited by block size?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_size_limit_controversy

Here it states that larger block size would allow **more transactions per second**.

If blocks have around constant mining rate (1 per 10 minutes) and fixed "amount" of transactions can fit in one block the statement logically follows. How are the size of one transaction and block size defined is a separate question.

The link also gives some context about the size limit.